# How to change index.php file path loading in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I need to change my index.php file loading path so I placed as follows,

```
httpdocs
    new_path
         index.php
```

and I updated my .htaccess as follow,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ new_path/index.php [NC,L]
```

but when I visit the http://www.mysite.com it says browser cannot find the page. Could anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* new_path/index.php [L]
```

Comment: I tried your example earlier I got the same result. I even tried with your reply but didn't work.

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Yea I'm getting 500 (internal sever)

Comment: So you get 404 for `http://www.mysite.com/`? What happens you open `http://www.mysite.com/new_path/index.php`?

Comment: if I load http://www.mysite.com/ Browser says page not found but if I open http://www.mysite.com/new_path/index.php url then it's working.

Comment: Also I just did quick test by removing following codes RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d                                     Then I visit http://www.mysite.com/ site working but CSS and javascripts are not loading. I get "500 Internal Server Error" for those files
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48055/discussion-between-fazlul-rahman-and-anubhava)

Comment: Hi sorry your updated didn't work but I did a small tweak and suddenly it worked.

Comment: There is no difference actually. `^` matches every URL anyway. Try updated code.

Answer (score 0):

I placed below bolded code above all I mentioned in my above question.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ new_path/index.php [NC,L]
```

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ new_path/index.php [NC,L]
```